# Appending custom icon glyphs to an NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, types

I need to embed icons in a string of text to be drawn onto the screen. The icons should act like any other character in the string and flow along with the text. The icons are not interactive any more than any other character in the string (i.e., clicking on them doesn't do anything, but you can select it in a copy/paste operation, although I'm fine that when it's pasted into another app, the custom glyphs are removed).

Is an NSAttributedString attachment the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Embedding special characters in your string has nothing to do with NSAttributedString, which is for string formatting (bold, italic, etc.). Since NSString is based on Unicode (UTF-16), all you need to do is look up the UTF-16 representation of your special characters and then embed that directly in your string literal.

Comment: My special character is not represented in the font. It is a custom glyph, so there is no unicode representation for it. NSAttributedStrings can have image attachments embedded in the text. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204929/saving-nsattributedstring-with-nstextattachment-into-file-how-to My question has to do with whether this mechanism is appropriate for what I want to do.